# Won't read full file c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to populate a linked list with creatures from a file. However, when I do it reads the first one but no other creatures. I cannot pass an int to get the number of creatures because it is not static.

I have the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void clearBuffer() {
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
}

void enterMagicalCreatureFromFile() {
    string filepath = "test.txt";
    ifstream creatureFile;
    creatureFile.open(filepath);
    if (!creatureFile) {
        cerr << "Unable to open file " << filepath << endl;
        return;
    }
    string name, description;
    float cost;
    char danger;
    int numCreated = 0;
    while (getline(creatureFile, name) && getline(creatureFile, description) && creatureFile >> danger && creatureFile >> cost) {
        cout << "name: " << name << " desc: " << description << " danger: " << danger << " cost: " << cost << endl;
        numCreated++;
    }
    cout << numCreated << " creatures from " << filepath << " have been added to the zoo" << endl;
}

int main() {
    enterMagicalCreatureFromFile();
}
```

The file test.txt looks like

```
Beholder
Giant center eye and twelve eye stalks above it.  It is a flying eyeball.  Mouth full of razor sharp teeth.  Eye stalks shoot various beams of magical death-dealing energy.
1
750.85
Banshee
The English Banshee is a fairy woman who wails when death is approaching.They do not cause death, only mourn it.  Banshees are almost always female, and are usually seen with long, dark, black hair and pale chees.  Their eyes also are usually red from crying.
0
15.5
Troll
Ugly and big.  Sometimes smell bad.
1
85648.34
Mike Wazowski
One-eyed, funny green monster.  A scare assistant to James P. Sullivan at Monsters, Inc.  Mike doesn't want any interruptions in his life.
0
455.32
Unicorn
The unicorn is a legendary creature that has been described since antiquity as a beast with a single large, pointed, spiraling horn projecting from its forehead. 
0
24.32
Sasquatch
The sasquatch is also called Big Food.  Bigfoot is a cryptid in American folklore, supposedly a simian-like creature that inhabits forests, especially those of the Pacific Northwest. Bigfoot is usually described as a large, hairy, bipedal humanoid.
1
39475.93
```

As I said the first creature "Beholder" loads and get added to the list perfectly, so I don't think my logic is in the list or the creature file.

I am stuck, any pointers?

Comment: `>>` leaves the line feed in the stream. It is then picked up by the `getline` on the next iteration, straddling the input.

Comment: clearBuffer doesn't take care of that?

Comment: According to the theory of "I need more coffee", it should indeed.

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Comment: @TobySpeight I have edited my post. I am still using namespace, but the undesired behavior is there

Comment: yes, if I have it in there it just hangs forever.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question to an MCVE - that enabled me to reproduce and diagnose the problem.

Comment: @JohnHamlettIV: _"clearBuffer doesn't take care of that?"_ It might, if it were ever called.

Comment: BTW, take care with `danger` (appropriately enough).  Because it's a `char`, reading into it will read a *character*, not a *number*.  IOW, you'll get `'0'` and `'1'` for the creatures from that file, which might be a surprise if you expected `0` and `1` (which are `'\0'` and `'\1'` respectively).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the double `cost`, there's a newline waiting in the  `creatureFile` stream.

We need to advance past that with `ignore()` before reading the next creature:

```
while (std::getline(creatureFile, name)
       && std::getline(creatureFile, description)
       && creatureFile >> danger
       && creatureFile >> cost)
{
    std::cout << "name: " << name
              << " desc: " << description
              << " danger: " << danger
              << " cost: " << cost
              << std::endl;
    ++numCreated;
    creatureFile.ignore(100, '\n');
}
```

Comment: Or, better yet, call the `clearBuffer()` function that you've already defined

Comment: @Lightness - after adapting it to work on streams other than `std::cin`.